# 3D Picture of Schur Quartic and 64 lines

Tags: algebraic-geometry, 3d, surfaces

The Schur Quartic, $x^4 -x y^3 = z^4 - z w^3$ has 64 lines.
The Clebsch Cubic, $w^3 + x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = (w+x+y+z)^3$ has 27 lines.

Work is required to show the Clebsch cubic nicely. Here's a more complicated form:
$81  (x^3 + y^3 + z^3) - 
  189  (x^2  y + x^2  z + x  y^2 + x  z^2 + y^2  z + y  z^2) + 
  54  x  y  z + 126  (x  y + x  z + y  z) - 9  (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) - 
  9  (x + y + z) + 1 = 0$
With that, we can [make a picture](https://blog.wolfram.com/2018/02/02/cultivating-new-solutions-for-the-orchard-planting-problem/):
[image: Clebsch]

Can someone make a nice 3D picture of the Schur Quartic? Bonus if the 64 lines are shown.

Comment: A smooth real quartic has at most 56 real lines: see https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04238

Comment: Oh, and there's the 56 real line case in Section 9.2. Looks like I'll need to make a picture.

Comment: Is there a three variable form of that?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "that"?

Comment: Is there a three variable form of the 56 real line quartic?

Comment: There is an explicit equation on p.42 of the linked paper. That has 4 variables z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3 but these are homogeneous coordinates on projective space; so to get a 3-variable version, you can set any variable equal to 1. This gives an open part of the full projective surface; the trick is to make sure you don't miss any of the lines by doing this.

Comment: I can give more detail if desired but maybe these comments are not the ideal medium...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment says, a smooth real quartic has at most 56 real lines, and indeed there is a unique smooth real quartic with exactly 56 lines. These results are due to Degtyarev, Itenberg, and Sertöz:

Lines on quartic surfaces.
*Math. Ann.* **368** (2017), no. 1-2, 753–809.

Here's a picture, of sorts, of that surface. Unfortunately only some of the lines are included:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Verifying the answer pointed at by Lazzaro. Showing 6 of the 56 lines. In Mathematica code, it's a ContourPlot of the following:

```
With[{w = 1}, 2 Sqrt[2] w (w - z) z (w + z) - x y (-3 w^2 + x^2 + y^2 - 3 z^2)] == 0
```

[image].